# Is it safe to share a presentation clicker with other presenters?

Tags: usb, security

When presenting slides as a speaker at a conference, I use a Logitech Wireless Presenter Remote ([link](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/presenters/r400-wireless-presenter.910-001354.html)). Other speakers often come up to ask whether they can borrow the remote to advance slides on their laptops. Because this device plugs into a USB on my machine, I'm concerned that it might be a bad security practice to share this remote with other people. At the same time, however, I believe that any hardware vulnerability here may be relatively unlikely. Which is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how much trust you have in the people you're lending it out to, if you have the device in view at all times, and how likely it is that you're being targeted by someone with the means to perform such a hack.

Essentially if you're handed an "unknown" USB device (of any type) to plug-in to your computer, and you do not know where it came from, you should be suspicious of it. I.e. don't pick up USB pen-drives that you found on the ground and plug it into your computer.

For your scneario: In order to exploit your computer, the malicious person would need to borrow your clicker device, take it somewhere you cannot see it, modify it (the hardware) to include the exploit, and then give it back to you.

Unless you're giving talks at DEF CON or somewhere similar, where you can expect someone is trying to actively hack you, or you have some very valuable information on your laptop, I don't think this type of attack is something the ordinary person needs to worry much about (assuming you know who the person you're lending the device to is).

Comment: Thanks! This information is very helpful. My question was focused on the case where I lend a clicker to someone who is not malicious but whose machine has been compromised. My impression from your answer is that it's an unlikely scenario unless the person who borrowed the clicker were intentionally malicious. I just was not sure whether any security risks, where malicious code could jump from a laptop to a clicker and then back to my laptop, may exist in real-world situations.

Comment: No, such a risk does not exist in the real world. Malicious code cannot simply “jump” onto this clicker. The only way this can happen is if the attacker specifically targeted this particular clicker and made an exploit specifically for it. I have never heard of such a thing happening in any practical, real-world situations.